# Redirecionar página atráves do link digitado na url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Eu preciso de uma página que quando eu carregá-la confira o link digitado por exemplo : www.test.com/myphp.php=10 se encontra determinado número ele redireciona para outra pagina , por exemplo : encontrada www.test.com/myphp.php=10 redireciona para www.test.com/news/10.php. Como posso fazer isso e que a tecnologia devo usar?

Comment: É só um caso ou queres redirecionar todas as urls para `news/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * User: rafaelphp
 * Date: 22/07/16
 * Time: 05:20 PM
 * File: index.php
 */

# exemplo basico - existem outras maneiras de fazer o que vc esta dizendo
# inclusive atraves do arquivo .htaccess(apache)

#vc deve validar dados vindo por get
$param = array();
$param['page'] = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : null ;

#vc pode validar as url procurando se o arquivo existe ou em uma funcao feita por vc
#isso pode ser feito antes da funcao 'switch; ou dentro do laco 'case'
$param['redir_url'] = "http://www.mydomain.com/news/";
$param['go']        = $param['redir_url'] . $param['page'] . ".php";

switch ($param['page'])
{
    case "10":
        header( "Location: " . $param['go'] );

        break;

    case "11":
        header( "Location: " . $param['go']);
        break;

    default:
        die("Error... pagina nao existe");
        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: valeu a ajuda amigo mas uns caras responderam aqui o que eu precisava http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531569/how-to-redirect-the-page-analyzing-url-typed dessa forma aqui ficou bem mais fácil